# Display abnormal for read a txt file

Tags: c++, getline

I wrote some codes below.The types of `title` and `authors` are char array and i can not change it.When data is inputed from keyboard the result is normal.

```
void BookException::getBook()
{
    cout<<"Id number: ";
    cin>>booknum;
    cout<<"Title: ";
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    cin.getline(title, sizeof(title), '\n');
    cout<<"Authors: ";
    cin.getline(authors, sizeof(authors), '\n');
    cout<<"Number of pages:";
    cin>>pagenum;
    cout<<"Price: ";
    cin>>price;
    cout<<"over"<<endl;
}
```

Here is input text below

```
1
How to program C++
Paul Deitel, Harvey Deitel
1028
112.83
```

But when I try to read some text from a txt file.It displaied like this:

`Id number: Title: Authors: Number of pages:Price: The no. 0 book error.
Title: 
Authors:
Number of pages: 0
Price: 0.00
Incorrect price.`

I think `getline` due to problem but i do not know how to fix it.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the file being passed in or opened in your code. Also you never print any of the variables after you read them or newlines. Using strings would be much easier but if you have to use char arrays I would suggest writing a function to convert from c-string to string and back also, see: [c_str()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/).

```
void BookException::getBook() {

    string booknum, title, authors, pagenum, price;
    ifstream fin;         //file in 
    fin.open("book.txt"); //Open the file


    getline(fin, booknum); //Read line from file first
    cout << "Id number: " << booknum << endl; //Then print
    getline(fin, title);
    cout << "Title: " << title << endl;
    getline(fin, authors);
    cout << "Authors: " << authors << endl;
    getline(fin, pagenum);
    cout << "Number of pages:" << pagenum << endl;
    getline(fin, price);
    cout << "Price: " << price << endl;
    cout << "over" << endl;

    fin.close(); //Close the file
}
```

I suggest reading this unless you understand all this: [input/output with files](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/)

`getline()` usage can be found [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/).